# How to make one image disappear when its rectangle intersects another image?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a picture that can be moved with the keyboard. What I want is: When I move it on top of another image, the other image disappears.

How can I do that?

That is my code so far, but it does not work. Thanks in advance.

Image3 is the moving one and Image6 is the one I want to disappear.

```
procedure TArmcutting.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    DoubleBuffered := true;
    if Intersectrect (overlay, Image3.BoundsRect, Image6.BoundsRect) then
    begin
        Image6.Visible := False;
    end;
end;
```

EDIT: Thanks everyone for your answers!

Comment: Since what you asked, and what was wrong with your question are different, this question isn't very useful to anybody else. Your question boils down to "I was confused about FormCreate, and thought that code there would get executed lots of times, but it doesn't", so the answer you accepted has nothing really to do with anybody in the future who would want to know how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now it only checkes intersection at application startup: `TForm.OnCreate` occurs only once. Place that code in the key event handler.

Also make sure both images have the same parent, otherwise you have to offset one of the rects to be comparable to the other.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check for intersection every time the image moves, not on the form creation.

Answer (score 1):

In the KeyUP/Down/Press event (whichever one you're using to handle the keys) or the procedure where you move the rectangle you need to check the intersection not just at creation.